# Filter sql by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query

```
select c.id, from_unixtime(max(cr.updated_at),'%Y-%m-%d') as last_activity
FROM clients as c
INNER JOIN clients_records as cr
ON c.id = cr.id_client
group by c.id
```

and I need to filter the records ,because I need the rows which  last_activity was at least a year ago

this query doesn't work:

```
select c.id, from_unixtime(max(cr.updated_at),'%Y-%m-%d') as last_activity
FROM clients as c
INNER JOIN clients_records as cr
ON c.id = cr.id_client
where from_unixtime(max(cr.updated_at),'%Y-%m-%d') < (SELECT  DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
group by c.id;
```

Comment: Try `where last_activity < (SELECT  DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR))`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'last_activity' in 'where clause'

Comment: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'last_activity' in 'where clause'" Oh yes ofcource select aliases can't be used in WHERE statements need some coffee.. `HAVING last_activity < (SELECT DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR))` should work better.

Comment: where from_unixtime(max(cr.updated_at),'%Y-%m-%d') < ( DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR))

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter *after* the aggregation, because your expression has an aggregation function.  Hence, `having`, not `where`:

```
select c.id, from_unixtime(max(cr.updated_at),'%Y-%m-%d') as last_activity
from clients c join
     clients_records cr
     on c.id = cr.id_client
group by c.id
having from_unixtime(max(cr.updated_at), '%Y-%m-%d') < curdate() - interval 1 year;
```

I also simplified your date comparison expression.

Note:  You can use a column alias in `having` (although not in `where`), so a further simplification is:

```
having last_activity < curdate() - interval 1 year;
```